# Powershell says it can't find path when using get-filehash

Tags: powershell

So first off, my code:

`gci -Path C:\ -Recurse | select FullName | %{Get-FileHash $_}`

I am getting an error altough the paths that `gci -Path C:\ -Recurse | select FullName` output are correct.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Get-FileHash](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn520872.aspx) also takes a `Path` so you can just pipe the `Get-ChildItem` cmdlet to it:

```
gci -Path C:\ -Recurse | Get-FileHash
```

Comment: Ah yes, this is much better and I recommend doing this. My answer shows why it wasn't working before, but this is the way forward in my opinion.

Comment: I still upvoted your answer since its valid but thought it could be improved ;-)

Answer (score 4):

`Select-Object` returns *an object* with the properties you specify. If you want it to return the *value* of a single property, use `-ExpandProperty`:

```
gci -Path C:\ -Recurse | select -ExpandProperty FullName | %{Get-FileHash $_}
```